# Windows service startup timeout prompted too soon

Tags: windows-services

When trying to start a windows service I have created I get the following error:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

What I find odd is that the error occurs as soon as I start up the service (within 2 seconds) so basically my service does not have time to start at all. I have added a new entry in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control setting the ServicesPipeTimeout to 30000 miliseconds but this does not correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a problem while trying to connect to a database. The error message was a bit confusing.